# 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context'

Tags: swift, swiftui

Im having been having this odd problem while coding in my Swift file  As soon as I inserted the '.animation' it gave me this error. Is anyone able to help me with this problem?

```swift
Button(action: {
    self.showDetail.toggle()
}) {
    Image(systemName: "chevron.right.circle")
        .imageScale(.large)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(showDetail ? 90 : 0)) // <- Type of expression is ambifuous without more context
        .padding()
        .animation(.easeInOut())
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! For readability, it is recommended to paste code instead of an image. See also [ask]. Also, show more code.

Answer (score 0):

`.animation(.easeInOut)` which has no parenthesis after .easeInout